# Как изменить свойство объекта (opacity) при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить свойства opacity в текстовых полях (otvet.otvetYes и otvet.otvetNo) при нажатии на кнопки Yes, No
Задача по нажатию на кнопку yes получить в кругу Yes. Пытаюсь это сделать через изменение свойства opacity, но не как не могу до него добраться.
Спасибо Вам за ответ!

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
@State var array: [UUID] = []

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Yes") {            } // Выводит Yes в первом поле
                    Button("No")  {            } // Выводит No в первом поле
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 55)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(otvetData) {
                    item in GameView(otvet: item)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    
    var otvet: Otvet
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
            Text("yes")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .offset(y: -5)
                .opacity(otvet.otvetYes ? 1 : 0)
            Text("no")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .offset(y: -5)
                .opacity(otvet.otvetNo ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}

struct Otvet: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var otvetYes: Bool
    var otvetNo: Bool
}

let otvetData = [
    Otvet(otvetYes: false, otvetNo: false),
    Otvet(otvetYes: false, otvetNo: false),
    Otvet(otvetYes: false, otvetNo: false),
    Otvet(otvetYes: false, otvetNo: false)
]
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать здесь `@ObservedObject` для обновления данных в массиве, отдельный вопрос при этом - у вас всего 2 кнопки Yes/No, может быть несколько кругов с ответами, поэтому непонятно по какому принципу связывать кнопки и круги, в связи с этим я оставил для простоты один круг, также я переименовал русифицированные переменные otvet -> answer

```
import SwiftUI

class Answer: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var answerYes = false
    @Published var answerNo = false
    
    init(answerYes: Bool, answerNo: Bool) {
        self.answerYes = answerYes
        self.answerNo = answerNo
    }
}

class Answers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Answer]()
    
    init(_ items: [Answer]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answers: Answers
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Yes") {
                        answers.items.first!.answerNo = false
                        answers.items.first!.answerYes = true
                    } // Выводит Yes в первом поле
                    Button("No") {
                        answers.items.first!.answerNo = true
                        answers.items.first!.answerYes = false
                    } // Выводит No в первом поле
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(answers.items) { item in
                    GameView(answer: item)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(answers: Answers([
            Answer(answerYes: false, answerNo: false)
        ]))
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answer: Answer
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
            Text("yes")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .offset(y: -5)
                .opacity(answer.answerYes ? 1 : 0)
            Text("no")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .offset(y: -5)
                .opacity(answer.answerNo ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Данный пример можно упростить - оставить 1 флаг для ответа yes/no и вместо opacity двух лейблов просто менять текст в одном, а чтобы управлять opacity, можно сделать свойство `answerYes` опциональным

```
class Answer: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var answerYes: Bool?
    
    init(answerYes: Bool?) {
        self.answerYes = answerYes
    }
}

class Answers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Answer]()
    
    init(_ items: [Answer]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answers: Answers
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Yes") {
                        answers.items.first!.answerYes = true // TODO: переделать логику обращения к элементам массива
                    } // Выводит Yes в первом поле
                    Button("No") {
                        answers.items.first!.answerYes = false // TODO: переделать логику обращения к элементам массива
                    } // Выводит No в первом поле
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(answers.items) { item in
                    GameView(answer: item)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(answers: Answers([
            Answer(answerYes: nil)
        ]))
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answer: Answer
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
            Text(answer.answerYes == nil ? "" : answer.answerYes! ? "yes" : "no")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .offset(y: -5)
                .opacity(answer.answerYes == nil ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
}
```

**Дополнение - добавление кнопок**

Можно перенести кнопки в `GameView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answers: Answers
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(answers.items) { item in
                GameView(answer: item)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(answers: Answers([
            Answer(answerYes: nil),
            Answer(answerYes: nil),
            Answer(answerYes: nil),
            Answer(answerYes: nil)
        ]))
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var answer: Answer
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // buttons
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Yes") {
                        answer.answerYes = true
                    } // Выводит Yes в первом поле
                    Button("No") {
                        answer.answerYes = false
                    } // Выводит No в первом поле
                }
            }
            // circle
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
                Text(answer.answerYes == nil ? "" : answer.answerYes! ? "yes" : "no")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .offset(y: -5)
                    .opacity(answer.answerYes == nil ? 0 : 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Дополнение 2 - условный вывод текста**

`opacity` можно вообще не использовать, просто сделав вывод текста опциональным через условие `if`

```
            // circle
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
                
                if let answerYes = answer.answerYes {
                    Text(answerYes ? "yes" : "no")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215686, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)))
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .offset(y: -5)
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ. Круто. Не могу понять как сделать из данного примера 4 круга?

Comment: @VladimirMayskiy что означают эти круги? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Первоначально было 4 круга с ответами. Вы сделали один.  Для примера я сделал только кнопки для первого круга. Я могу использовать цикл for для добавления еще несколько комплектов кнопок в зависимости от количества вопросов (кругов). Мне пришлось добавить в файл AppDelegate let contentView = ContentView(answers: Answers([Answer(answerYes: false, answerNo: false)])) для работы проекта. До этого была ошибка. Если я добавляю еще строки Answers([Answer(answerYes: false, answerNo: false)], то на View добавляются еще вопросы (Круги). Но мне кажется, что добавлять через AppDelegate это неправильно.

Comment: @VladimirMayskiy см дополнение

Comment: Спасибо большое @schmidt9.